# Add single quote to string

Tags: hive

Given this data:

```
col1
----
foo
bar
```

I want concatenate the rows together, and end up with **'foo','bar'**.
Using collect_set gets me an array, concat_ws gets me a comma separated string.
select

```
concat_ws(',',collect_set(col1))
```

I cannot figure out how to get the single quotes in there.

`concat('''',col1,'''')` just returns the value of col1.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes.

```
concat('\'',col1,'\'')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's perfect!